# Boost unordered map pretty printer is printing value multiple times along with unwanted values

Tags: python, boost, gdb, pretty-print, unordered-map

I am trying to add a pretty printer for boost::unordered_map  by adding  a new printer to the existing list of boost pretty printers from here:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport https://github.com/ruediger/Boost-Pretty-Printer

However a lot of values are printed multiple times and some unwanted character when I try to print my map. I am not sure what else modification to my existing code should be done to make it print values only once, with out any unwanted characters. Here is loop where I update myMap in myMap.cpp:

```
 for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
 {
 string s = to_string(i);
 myMap[s] = i;
 }
```

and when I print myMap in gdb as

```
(gdb)p myMap
```

I get the result as below:

```
$1 = boost::unordered::detail = {"1" = 1, "0" = 0, "2" = 2, "1" = 1, "0" = 0, "3" = 3, 
"2" = 2, "1" = 1, "0" = 0, "4" = 4, "3" = 3, "2" = 2, "1" = 1, "0" = 0, "5" = 5, "4" = 4, 
"3" = 3, "2" = 2, "1" = 1, "0" = 0, "6" = 6, "5" = 5, "4" = 4, "3" = 3, "2" = 2, "1" = 1, 
 "0" = 0, "7" = 7, "10" = 10, "6" = 6, "5" = 5, "4" = 4, "3" = 3, "2" = 2, "1" = 1, 
"0" = 0, "8" = 8, "7" = 7, "10" = 10, "6" = 6, "5" = 5, "4" = 4, "3" = 3, "2" = 2, 
"1" = 1, "0" = 0, "9" = 9, "8" = 8, "7" = 7, "10" = 10, "6" = 6, "5" = 5, "4" = 4, 
"3" = 3, "2" = 2, "1" = 1, "0" = 0, 
" \204`", '\000' <repeats 13 times>, "\321\n\002", '\000' <repeats 181 times>... = 0, 
"9" = 9, "8" = 8, "7" = 7, "10" = 10, "6" = 6, "5" = 5, "4" = 4, "3" = 3, "2" = 2, 
"1" = 1, "0" = 0}
```

My python code of pretty printer looks like this:

```
@_register_printer
class BoostUnorderedMap:
"Pretty Printer for boost::unordered_map"
printer_name = 'boost::unordered_map'
version = '1.40'
type_name_re = '^boost::unordered::unordered_map<.*>$'

class _iterator:
def __init__(self,fields):
   type_1 = fields.val.type.template_argument(0)
   type_2 = fields.val.type.template_argument(1)

   self.buckets = fields.val['table_']['buckets_']
   self.bucket_count = fields.val['table_']['bucket_count_']
   self.bucket_size = fields.val['table_']['size_']
   self.current_bucket = 0
   self.value = 0
   self.iteration = 0
   self.temp_node = 0
   self.bucket_to_start = 0
   pair = "std::pair<%s const, %s>" % (type_1, type_2)
   self.pair_pointer = gdb.lookup_type(pair).pointer()
   self.base_pointer = gdb.lookup_type("boost::unordered::detail::value_base< %s >" % pair).pointer()
   self.node_pointer = gdb.lookup_type("boost::unordered::detail::ptr_node<std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, int> >").pointer()
   self.node = self.buckets[self.current_bucket]['next_']



def __iter__(self):
    return self

def next(self): 
    while not self.node:
            self.current_bucket = self.current_bucket + 1
            if self.current_bucket >= self.bucket_count:
                raise StopIteration
            self.node = self.buckets[self.current_bucket]['next_']

    iterator = self.node.cast(self.node_pointer).cast(self.base_pointer).cast(self.pair_pointer).dereference()   
        self.node = self.node['next_']

        return ('%s' % iterator['first'], iterator['second'])

def __init__(self, val):
self.val = val

def children(self):
return self._iterator(self)

def to_string(self):
return "boost::unordered::detail"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what is going wrong exactly without learning more about Boost internals.  If it were me I would probably hack the "next" method to add some debugging prints to see what is going awry.

Anyway, one thing stood out in your Python code.  Right now you are returning the child elements like this:

```
    return ('%s' % iterator['first'], iterator['second'])
```

However, the usual way to use this API is to return the key and values of the map as separate children, and then have a display_hint method that returns "map".  See

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing-API.html

You can do this pretty easily with "yield" in the next method.